# C char* to java String in JNA

Tags: java, jna

I have function in C:

```
void MyFunc(char *value string);
```

I define it in JNA in Java like

```
void MyFunc(String value)
```

Is my definition good?

Comment: `void MyFunc(char *value string);` does not compile...

Comment: you most probably need `char16_t*`. Java `char` is not the equivalent of C++ `char`.

Comment: You have not provided us enough information to answer whether your definition is good.  As others have indicated, Java's `String` is immutable, so it would map to a `const char*`.  You do not give any information on whether `MyFunc()` performs any manipulation on the provided string.  Any C-side modifications to the string would never be seen in Java -- in which case, using a Pointer or other Java data type may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your definition is valid (except misprint in your C++ code, of course).

Did you look at the JNA docs: https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html ? They perfectly specify what to use for each data type

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html) you should use `const char*` (Java Strings are immutable)

Comment: But it should work with `char *` as well. If you reassign the pointer inside the function - it should not affect wrapping java code.

Comment: OP is starting with a C definition which is not `const`.  Therefore whether his answer is correct is dependent on whether the C variable is mutable or not.